# How can I read uncertain data form file and store it in struct

Tags: c

I have a trouble to read data from a file.

**The file:**

```
0   0.0
0   0.0
0   0.0
0   0.0
0   0.0
0   0.0
23 liu zhengzhi 90
0   0.0
0   0.0
0   0.0
0   0.0
0   0.0
0   0.0
0   0.0
0   0.0
0   0.0
0   0.0
0   0.0
0   0.0
0   0.0
```

in the file you not sure one line is `0  0.0` or `int char* char* double`and I need to read it to a struct.

**The struct:**

```
typedef struct Credit
{
    char first_name[20]="";
    char last_name[20]="";
    int account_number=0;
    double balance=0.0;
}account;
```

How can I do it.

Comment: Read the first `int`. That will tell you which type of record you have. Once you know it's the type your `struct` will hold, read the remaining fields.

Comment: First read the line into a buffer so you can tinker with it to your liking. Then craft a test to determine which case you're in. Finally re-read from the buffer into the appropriate structure.

Comment: You can read the line into a string, perform tests on the string, and extract your data from the string as informed by your tests.

Comment: Are these guaranteed to be the _only_ two cases?  Or, can there be others?

Comment: ＠ryyker only two case

Comment: The proper way is to read file line-by-line and use regular expressions to find matches.

Comment: One case always `0   0.0` and the other case always `23 liu zhengzhi 90`???

Comment: @ barak manos another case is `int char* char* double`  `23 liu zhengzhi 90` is an example.

Comment: do not typedef structs.   typedef'ing structs clutters the code, leads to misunderstandings, and clutters the compiler name space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that there are only the two cases, parsing is simplified:

***1)*** Open/read file using `fopen()`
***2)*** read line by line using `fgets()` in while loop
***3)*** tokenize and store elements of each new line using `strtok()` (or `strtok_r()` if threaded)
***4)*** Use count of tokens per line, and test each string token for contents
***5)*** For counts of 2 tokens, skip line
***6)*** For counts of 4 tokens, convert 1st & 4th strings.   ( `atoi()` & `atof()` )
***7)*** Assign parsed values to struct members.
***8)*** close file - `fclose()`

If there is a possibility of  more than 1 data line, then you might want an array of struct to contain data:

For the data file you have shown, here is a very simple parsing routine example using these steps:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

typedef struct Credit
{
    char first_name[20];
    char last_name[20];
    int account_number;
    double balance;
}ACCOUNT;

ACCOUNT account[10];

int main()
{
    char file[]={"C:\\Play\\account.txt"};
    char line[1024];
    char *token = {0};
    char delim[]={" \r\n\t"};
    int count, i, j;
    char array[4][80];//should be dynamically allocated, this for illustration

    FILE *fp = fopen(file, "r");
    if(fp)
    {
        j = 0;
        while (fgets(line, 1024, fp) != NULL)
        {
            token = strtok(line, delim);
            i = -1;
            while(token)
            {
                i++;
                strcpy(array[i], token);
                token = strtok(NULL, delim);
            }
            if(i==3)
            {
                account[j].account_number = atoi(array[0]);
                strcpy(account[j].first_name, array[1]);
                strcpy(account[j].last_name, array[2]);
                account[j].balance = atof(array[3]);
            }
            j++;//for next in array of account
            memset(array, 0, 320);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken you don't seem to increment `j`, you might want to otherwise you will be overwriting the first value in the account array each time.

Comment: @Daboyzuk - You are right, I missed that.   Edited to add, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Parse the string, multiple times if needed.

Use `" %n"` to determine success.  `"%n"` specifies to save the number of `char` scanned.  Since it is last, it will only be changed if the scan was complete.  Useful for looking for extra garbage on the line too.

```
// Return number of fields successfully scanned 4, 2, 0
int ParseLine(account *dest, const char *src) {
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(src, "%d%19s%19s%lf %n", &dest->account_number, dest->first_name, 
     dest->last_name, &dest->balance, &n);
  // If all fields scanned and no extra garbage ...
  if (n && src[n] == 0) {
    return 4;
  }

  n = 0;
  sscanf(src, "%d%lf %n", &dest->account_number, &dest->balance, &n);
  if (n && src[n] == 0) {
    dest->first_name[0] = dest->last_name[0] = 0;
    return 2;
  }

  return 0; // nothing scanned
}
```

---

A more robust test would insure `first/last` do not exceed 19 `char` by testing if a longer name was readable.

```
  char first[20+1];
  first[19] = 0;
  char last[20+1];
  last[19] = 0;
  sscanf(src, "%d%20s%20s%lf %n", &dest->account_number, first, 
     last, &dest->balance, &n);
  // If all fields scanned, no extra garbage, no long name ...
  if (n && src[n] == 0 && first[19] == 0 && last[19] == 0) {
    strcpy(dest->first_name, first); 
    strcpy(dest->last_name, last); 
    return 4;
  }
```

---

Code could use `"%d %19s %19s %lf %n"` instead of `"%d%19s%19s%lf %n"`.  It may be more readable, but since `"%d"`, `"%s"`, `"%f"` consume leading white-space by themselves anyways - it makes no functional difference.

Answer (score 0):

1.) One way to do it.Use getline to read the line one by one. Read returns the number of character in a line. If the number of characters is 4 then skip it and if its 15 then store it in struct as you wish

```
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
       if(read==15)
       {
        //store it in struct
       }
     }
```

2.) Another way is use string tokenizer and if the token is 4 store it in 
struct.

There will be many ways to do this. Common baseline is that one line has more characters and other lines have same number of characters or words. So I wouldn't call this uncertain data. It has set pattern to it .

Comment: what if the account holders name is NOT exactly the same as the example?

Comment: read==15 was just an example. If it is more than 4 then it is an account holders name. You can then parse it however you wish. But you are right. I will modify my answer a bit more receptive.

Answer (score 0):

the following code, cleanly compiles, works
and is a suggested method of reading the indicated file.

Not everyone will agree with the use of 'continue'

```
#include <stdio.h>   // fopen, fclose, fgets
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit, EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string.h>  // memset

struct account
{
    char first_name[20];
    char last_name[20];
    int account_number;
    double balance;
};

#define MAX_LINE_LEN (1024)

int main( int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    if( 2 != argc )
    { // then missing file name argument
        printf( "usage: %s <accountFileName>\n", argv[0] );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, correct number of command line arguments

    printf( "processing file: %s\n", arg[1] );

    FILE *fp = NULL;

    if( NULL == (fp = fopen( argv[1], "r" ) ) )
    { // then fopen failed
        perror( "fopen for input file failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    struct account* accountList = NULL;
    char buffer[MAX_LINE_LEN] = { '\0' };
    int numAccounts = 0;

    while( fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, fp ) )
    {
        if( '0' == buffer[0] ) // assumes no 'id' starts with 0
        { // then, 'this' record not of interest

            // clear for next loop iteration
            memset( buffer, 0x00, sizeof buffer );
            continue; // go to top of loop and get another record
        }

        // when get here, then record of interest

        // used so realloc failure does not lose pointer to allocated memory
        struct account* temp = NULL;

        if( NULL == (temp = realloc( accountList, sizeof( struct account )*numAccounts+1 ) ) )
        { // then malloc failed
            perror( "realloc failed" );

            printf( "realloc failed for record number: %d\n", numAccounts+1);
            free( accountList );
            fclose( fp );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, malloc successful

        accountList = temp;  // update pointer to allocated memory

        // clear the new account struct area
        memset( &(accountList[numAccounts]), 0x00, sizeof( struct account ) );

        // following assumes all records are properly formatted
        if( 4 != sscanf( buffer, "%d %19s %19s %lf", 
                        &accountList[numAccounts].account_number,
                         accountList[numAccounts].first_name,
                         accountList[numAccounts].last_name,
                        &accountList[numAccounts].balance ) )
        { // then sscanf failed
            perror( "sscanf for record parsing failed" );
            // add error handling here, following is suggested error handling
            printf( "sscanf/record parsing failed for record number: %d\n", numAccounts+1 );
            free( accountList );
            fclose (fp );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, sscanf successful

        // clear for next loop iteration
        memset( buffer, 0x00, sizeof buffer );
    } // end while loop

    // done with file, so close it
    fclose( fp );

    // --add processing of account list here--

    free( accountList );

    return(0);
} // end function: main
```

Comment: the code could be made more robust by checking of the name (first/last) is greater than 19 characters and handling that problem